# Injecting Endpoint parameters wso2

Tags: wso2, endpoint, integrator, wso2-esb

I am new to the WSO2 ESB. I want to create an API in which I want to add an endpoint URL following the documentation(i know that there are more easy methods but this is that I want to test to follow because the others I already test them):
    https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI6xx/Injecting+Parameters+using+a+file
I follow step by step the documentation...but the error is the following:

ERROR - ClientUtils The system cannot infer the transport information from the $FILE:test URL.
ERROR - Axis2Sender Unexpected error during sending the message out
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The system cannot infer the transport information from the $FILE:test URL.

[code for call ep]:

```
 <call blocking="true">
        <endpoint key="test-ep"/>
    </call>
```

[code ep]:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoint name="test-ep" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <address uri="$FILE:test">
        <enableSec/>
        <timeout>
            <duration>600000</duration>
             <responseAction>fault</responseAction>
        </timeout>
        <suspendOnFailure>
            <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>
             <initialDuration>0</initialDuration>
            <progressionFactor>1.0</progressionFactor>
             <maximumDuration>0</maximumDuration>
        </suspendOnFailure>
        <markForSuspension>
            <errorCodes>-1</errorCodes>`enter code here`
        </markForSuspension>
    </address>
</endpoint>
```

[file.properties in carbon home and set in integrator.bat how documentation]:

```
test=http://localhost:8280/services/document
```

Comment: the problem is been riesolving, my version of integrator was old (6.4.0) and this function not work. Now I use 6.6.0 of wso2 integrator and it work as documentation

Answer (score 0):

whenever you start the run integrator.bat, you can pass that location.

Eg:integrator.bat -Dproperties.file.path=yourlocation(Eg:D:\env_variables)\file.properties

once deploy the .car file automatically it will replace the keyword with respective value